# What makes table web scraping with rvest package sometimes fail?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm playing with [rvest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rvest/versions/0.3.4) package and trying to figure out why sometimes it fails to scrape objects that definitely seem tables.

Consider for instance a script like this:

```
require(rvest)
url <- "http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/options.asp?symb=SPY"
population <- url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="options"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody') %>%
  html_table()
population
```

If I inspect `population`, it's an empty list:

```
> population
list()
```

Another example:

```
require(rvest)
url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/options?straddle=false"
population <- url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Col1-1-OptionContracts-Proxy"]/section/section[1]/div[2]') %>%
  html_table()
population
```

I was wondering if the use of [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/download.html) is mandatory - as explained [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r) - or if the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your current xpaths actually select just the table. In both cases I think you need to pass an html table to `html_table` as under the hood there is:

```
html_table.xml_node(.) : html_name(x) == "table"
```

Also, long xpaths are too fragile especially when applying a path valid for browser rendered content versus rvest return html - as javascript doesn't run with rvest. Personally, I prefer nice short CSS selectors. You can use the second fastest selector type of class and only need specify a single class

```
require(rvest)
url <- "http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/options.asp?symb=SPY"
population <- url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_node('.optionchain') %>%
  html_table()
```

The table needs cleaning of course, due to "merged" cells in source, but you get the idea.

With xpath you could do:

```
require(rvest)
url <- "http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/options.asp?symb=SPY"
population <- url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath='//table[2]') %>%
  html_table()
```

Note: I reduce the xpath and work with a single node which represents a table.

---

For your second:

Again, your xpath is not selecting for a table element. The table class is multi-valued but a single correctly chosen class will suffice in xpath i.e. `//*[contains(@class,"calls")]` . Select for a single table node.

```
require(rvest)
url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/options?straddle=false"
population <- url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath='//*[contains(@class,"calls")]') %>%
  html_table()
```

Once again, my preference is for a css selector (less typing!)

```
require(rvest)
url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/options?straddle=false"
population <- url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_node('.calls') %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: Could you please explain how can I know the value of the CSS selector I'm interested in? You can edit your answer or reply here below.

Comment: 1) Learn and practice css selectors. On my [SO profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr?tab=profile) there is a section called links I frequently share. That has a selection of good css selector resources. Additionally, you can right click inspect on an element then right click copy css selector - that will give you a longer than required path normally but can be used as a starting point for reducing. There are also tools like selector gadget - but again, that path is a bit verbose normally. Learning css selectors throughly from the resources in my links and others is best.